# Static image url is returned without MEDIA_URL

Tags: python, django

i followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tT2JOpfelSg) about displaying profile pictures on website, i did everything correctly (i hope so) but instead of returning example.com/media/posters/pic1.jpg it returns example.com/pictures/pic1.jpg [(real example)](https://image.prntscr.com/image/CxDu9FRFT-aBBUW1wR31Yw.png)

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    movies = {'movies' : movie.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'index.html', movies)
```

models.py

```
class movie(models.Model):
poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='posters')
```

and html

```
{% for a in movies %}
<img src="{{ a.poster }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

i added `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to urls.py file

also, i had to use a.poster instead of poster.image.url, it just returned unknow, different django version i assume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `{% get_media_prefix %}.`

Comment: Answer should be described in more detail.

Comment: just adding it before {{ a.poster }} works as well thanks